# Apk publishing from draft

Tags: android, android-studio

I am intending to publish my first apk which is in draft mode. Google Console requires me to create a version first.

I fill the application out, but I got a similar message as 'you must either add a new APK or disable an existing APK to create a new version' when I  pressed the 'Confirm' (or similar).

I can not find any doc about this issue.
It is very weird because I selected the very apk in draft mode before ask to create new version in order to publish it.

**Updates:**

*At first, my mistake was to click in Revision button before upload the signed apk. But, after did, the error below arouse.*

**The error was :**

> apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures

and I found out the reason I could not upload my App, after hours and hours in searching everywhere: at the creation of a signed apk, does not check V2 only in Signature Versions, but V1 (or V1 and V2). That is, never check V2 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change/increment every time your `version code` when you are going to upload/update apk to playstore. (Before generating signed apk)

**Example :** `versionCode 1` need to change `versionCode 2`

**Note :** You should increment your `versionCode` & `versionName` on every update.

**How to Update apk on PlayStore :** 
 Select your project on playstore -> Click on Release Management -> app release -> ....

In your **build.gradle(Module: app):**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I uploaded only one, the draft one. Do I must delete, change Build Gradle to an new version, make a new upload? Sorry, I did not understand.

Comment: Go to your project on Android studio and generate signed apk by increase the versionCode , next i'm explaining you @MauroSimoes

Comment: Ok. I made a edition in Gradle to version & name to '2'.

Comment: Have to generated signed apk

Comment: Ok. I did the generation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165056/discussion-between-mauro-simoes-and-abhishek-kumar).

Comment: I found out the reason I could not upload my App, after hours and hours in searching everywhere: at the creation of a signed apk, does not check V2 only, but V1 (or V1 and V2). That is, never check V2 only.

Comment: Yes at the time of generating signed apk you have to check both of the V1 and V2 , Have to solved you issue ?? @MauroSimoes

Comment: Yes, I had. Thank you.